# abstract algebra, Sylow $p$-subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

May I have assistance on the following two exam questions where $G$ is finite group and $p$ is prime. $\DeclareMathOperator{\Syl}{Syl}$

1)$\;\;$ If $P\in \Syl_{p}(G)$ and $K$ is a subgroup of $G$ containing $P$, prove that $P\in \Syl_{p}(K)$; and$\;\;$
2)$\;\;$ If $K$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $Q\in \Syl_{p}(K)$, prove that $gQg^{-1}\in \Syl_{p}(gKg^{-1})$.

My attempt for 1):$\;\;$ Since   $P\in \Syl_{p}(G)$, then $G$ must consist of a number of Sylow $p$-subgroups, say $G= \{P_{1}, P_{2}, ...P, ...P_{n}\}$, at least one of which, say $P$, is contained in $K$.

Hence one can write that $\Syl_{p}(K)\in \Syl_{p}(G)$ and thus that $P\in \Syl_{p}(K)$.

My attempt for 2) follows similar outline. If $Q\in \Syl_{p}(K)$, this implies that $K$ can be written as a set of Sylow $p$-subgroups, say $K=\{Q_{1},Q_{2},..Q,..Q_{n}\}$.

Hence $gKg^{-1}=\{gQ_{1}g^{-1},...gQg^{-1}, ..gQ_{n}g^{-1}\}$, and so we can state that $gQg^{-1}\in \Syl_{p}(gKg^{-1})$.

I am new to abstract algebra and am finding it very difficult. I do not know if my attempts carry any validity.

Thanks in advance for any "wisdom".

Comment: What is your definition of a $p$-Sylow?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Please ask only one question per post. Having multiple questions in the same post is discouraged and such posts may be put on hold, see [meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6464).

Comment: To Shaun: My sincere apologies for asking two questions rather than one. Thank you for the advice. Have noted the need for a more accurate title.

Comment: To Bernard: "I used the definition that if p is prime, then a Sylow p-subgroup P of a group G is a maximal p-subgroup". I was not cognisant of the implication given in paragraph two of Martund's detailed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempts are incomplete, you don't argue why "one can write that $\operatorname{Syl}_{p}(K)\in \operatorname{Syl}_{p}(G)$ and thus that $P\in \operatorname{Syl}_{p}(K)$".

The correct argument relies on the definition of Sylow $p$-subgroups of a group. $P\subset G$ is called a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ if order of $P$ is the largest power of $p$ dividing order of $G$.

Let order of G be $p^mr,$ where $p\not| r$. Then order of $P$ is $p^m$ and it is the largest exponent of $p$ dividing order of $K$ (which follows from Lagrange's theorem), hence part (1) follows.

For part (2), observe that $gQg^{-1}$ is a subgroup of $gKg^{-1}$ and order of $gQg^{-1}$ is same as order of $Q$ and order of $gKg^{-1}$ is same as order of $K$. Now, we know that order of $Q$ is the largest power of $p$ dividing order of $K$, thus order of $gQg^{-1}$ is the largest power of $p$ dividing order of $gKg^{-1}$, and we are done.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Now I see where my reasoning is "limited".